# Copy rows without triggering a macro VBA

Tags: excel, vba, automation, copy

There's a few questions relating to this subject but I'm struggling a bit.

I have a MASTER `sheet` that stores various information. I use `Column B` to hide/unhide other `columns`. So for each different value entered in Column B, it will display the appropriate `Columns`. e.g. If `X` is entered in `Column B`, `Col C:F` will be displayed and `Col G:I` will be hidden.

This works fine but I want to automatically `copy` identical values from this sheet to separate `sheets`. e.g. grab all `X's` in MASTER and copy to a separate `sheet` that contains only `X's`.

I can do this but only through the use of a `macro` that needs to be triggered. This isn't very efficient if I need to `copy` numerous `rows`. Especially if you've only updated 1 `row` but need to copy everything.

**I want to automatically auto-copy as soon as a value is entered. Without needing to trigger a macro**

This is the `script` the hides/unhides specific `columns` in the MASTER `sheet`:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo safe_exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim t As Range
        For Each t In Intersect(Target, Range("B:B"))
            Select Case (t.Value)
                Case "Change of Numbers"
                    Columns("B:BP").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                    Columns("H:BL").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                    'do nothing
            End Select
        Next t

    End If

safe_exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

**As I can't add a separate Worksheet_Change to this script to auto-copy across I'm a bit confused in how to do this**

I'm currently using the script below. This copies the appropriate `rows` to the respective `sheet`. But it only works when triggered. I'm hoping to automatically `copy` the `row` once filled in.

@Gexas, how is this?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo safe_exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim t As Range
        For Each t In Intersect(Target, Range("B:B"))
            Select Case (t.Value)
                Case "Change of Numbers"
                    Columns("B:BP").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                    Columns("H:BL").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                    'do nothing
            End Select
        Next t

    End If
safe_exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rng As Range, sht1 As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet

    Set sht1 = Worksheets("MASTER")
    Set sht2 = Worksheets("CON")

    sht2.UsedRange.ClearContents

    With Intersect(sht1.Columns("B:BP"), sht1.UsedRange)
        .Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False ' unhide columns
        If .Parent.AutoFilterMode Then .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

        .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="Change of Numbers"

        .Range("A:F, BL:BO").Copy Destination:=sht2.Cells(2, "B")
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

        .Range("H:BK").EntireColumn.Hidden = True ' hide columns
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: So call it from the `Worksheet_Change` event? I feel like I'm missing something here...

Comment: Huh? You've completely lost me. Why would `FilterAndCopy()` need to be in the MASTER sheet - it's implicitly public.

Comment: I'm obviously a bit lost here. I don't understand what needs to go into what Worksheet.

Comment: What am I calling from the Worksheet_Change event?

Comment: `FilterAndCopy()` as I understand the question.

Comment: I've amended the output in the question. Is this correct?

Comment: If not could you post the correct answer so I can accept it

Comment: I am bit lost too. If you need macro to trigger automatically, you can use `Worksheet_change` event. I see that you edited it into code. But you have to delete `Sub FilterAndCopy()` part, because it will cause an error now. Also this whole script has to be in sheet (MASTER) where changes happen, since `Worksheet_change` event is sheet specific.

Comment: @Gexas, that sheet already has a Worksheet_Change due to the hide/unhide function. I can't call a separate Worksheet_Change for the auto-copy

Comment: Put it all in same `Worksheet_change` event. It does not matter how many actions it makes. Or I am missing something?

Comment: It would be great if you could put this in the form an an answer. I can't get the order right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Filter and Copy

If you move the 'Sub' into the sheet code (Master), you can lose the 'sht1' in it like you did in the 'Private Sub', if not just add the line FilterAndCopy appropriately into the 'Private Sub'.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    On Error GoTo safe_exit

    ' Something has changed in Column "B"
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then

        Application.EnableEvents = False

    ' *******************
        FilterAndCopy ' *
    ' *******************

        Dim t As Range

        For Each t In Intersect(Target, Range("B:B"))
            Select Case (t.Value)
                Case "Change of Numbers"
                    Columns("B:BP").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                    Columns("H:BL").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                    'do nothing
            End Select
        Next t

    End If

safe_exit:

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub


'****************
Sub FilterAndCopy()

    Dim rng As Range, sht1 As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet

    Set sht1 = Worksheets("MASTER")
    Set sht2 = Worksheets("CON")

    sht2.UsedRange.ClearContents

    With Intersect(sht1.Columns("B:BP"), sht1.UsedRange)
        .Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False        ' unhide columns
            If .Parent.AutoFilterMode Then .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
                .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="Change of Numbers"
                .Range("A:F, BL:BO").Copy Destination:=sht2.Cells(2, "B")
            .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
        .Range("H:BK").EntireColumn.Hidden = True ' hide columns
    End With

End Sub
'****************
```

Comment: But `FilterAndCopy()` still won't be triggered automatically, or I am wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`Worksheet_Change` event can have both of your functions inside. Since code is read from first to last line, with with order VBA will copy content from your second code and later hides columns. Code below should work, assuming everything else is good with. Note that I can not test it and did not check for other errors. Just changed order.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rng As Range, sht1 As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet

    Set sht1 = Worksheets("MASTER")
    Set sht2 = Worksheets("CON")

    sht2.UsedRange.ClearContents

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo safe_exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False

        With Intersect(sht1.Columns("B:BP"), sht1.UsedRange)
          .Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False       ' unhide columns
           If .Parent.AutoFilterMode Then .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

            .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="Change of Numbers"

            .Range("A:F, BL:BO").Copy Destination:=sht2.Cells(2, "B")
            .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

            .Range("H:BK").EntireColumn.Hidden = True ' hide columns
        End With

        Dim t As Range
        For Each t In Intersect(Target, Range("B:B"))
            Select Case (t.Value)
            Case "Change of Numbers"
                Columns("B:BP").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                Columns("H:BL").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                'do nothing
            End Select
        Next t

    End If

    safe_exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Nope, every time there is a change anywhere on the worksheet, sheet CON is being changed. No need to do this unless a value in a cell in the B column has changed to "Change of Numbers".

Comment: Oh I see what you talking about now, I'll change my answer to correct order then.

Comment: That's nice. Now I want to manually trigger FilterAndCopy (run macro).